# NLS_LANG parameter

Tags: oracle-xe, nls

Is it possible to change `NLS_LANG` settings on the **server** after installation `Oracle 11.2 XE`? (I am not thinking about alter session.) As you know one can not choose db characterset nor nls_lang while installing this product.

Since my previous version of `Oracle 10 XE` had differenet `NLS_LANG` setting I would like it to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change NLS_LANG on server and session level.
Changing database characterset is almost impossible when the original characterset is not US7ASCII.

To change NLS_LANG:

- Environment variable NLS_LANG
- System environment variable NLS_LANG
- Use registry HKLM\software\oracle... and add string value.

Remember to use quoting when necessary on Windows when there are spaces in the region.

Comment: Tnx. My charachterset is AL32UTF8. I wil try as you said. Tnx once again.